# date in Jqgrid shows 1 day off.

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

In my application I am using JqGrid.in that JqGrid having Start date and close Date .when I am executing that application on same matching the Jqgrid all start date and close date shows correct dates.but after hosting that project on server and see application at client side it shows previous date in JqGrid.

Actually I am not understand why that should happen.
If having any suggestion on that please give some suggestion on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is miss match in server and client machine time zone then that issue is occur .when setting same time zone in server and client machine then date displaying in grid is correct.